# Is it okay to compare a pointer and an integer in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing some code that maps virtual addresses to physical addresses.

I have code along these lines:

```
if (address > 0xFFFF)
   Status = XST_FAILURE; // Out of range
else if (address <= 0xCFFF || address >= 0xD400) {
   // Write to OCM
   Xil_Out8(OCM_HIGH64_BASEADDR + OCM_OFFSET + address, data);
else { // (address >= 0xD000)
   // Write to external CCA
   Status = ext_mem_write(address, data);
```

I get a compiler warning: 
`comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]`

I realize that I'm comparing two different types (pointer and integer), but is this an issue?  After all, comparing a pointer to an integer is exactly what I want to do.

Would it be cleaner to define pointer constants to compare to instead of integers?

```
const int *UPPER_LIMIT = 0xFFFF;
...
if (address > UPPER_LIMIT ){
    ....
```

Comment: It's better to convert pointers to integers, rather than integers to pointers. It's because the comparison operators for pointers are not well defined, but for integers they are.

Comment: The pointer is usually an unsigned integer, comparing it to a signed integer might produce unexpected results due to the conversion.

Comment: Once you are confident that what you do works, use a cast to defeat the compiler warning, rather than disable the warning. But only then ;). Perhaps implementing the advice from @EugeneSh. will remove the warning.

Comment: It is in general an issue because although C permits it, it is not *usually* what people intend to do.  Such comparisons arise far more often because the pointer was intended to be dereferenced to yield an integer value for comparison.  Moreover, given an integer value not somehow derived from a pointer, C provides no promises whatever about the meaning of that value converted to a pointer.  It *certainly* doesn't promise that such a pointer value refers to any particular physical address.

Comment: this is one of many undefined behaviors. it's needed in your case, however. it's totally implementation dependent. you will need to test how your compiler behaves.

Comment: Is it okay to compare an Elephant and a Tractor?  They may weigh about the same, be the same size, and both enjoy dirt.  But the comparison won't have much meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clean way is to use contants of type `uintptr_t`, which is defined to be an unsigned integer that can uniquely map between pointers and integers.

This should be defined by `#include <stdint.h>`.  If it is not defined then it indicates that either your compiler doesn't follow the C standard, or the system does not have a flat memory model.

It's intended to be mapped in the "obvious" way , i.e. one integer per byte in ascending order. The standard doesn't absolutely guarantee that but as a quality of implementation issue it's hard to see anything else happening.

Example:

```
uintptr_t foo = 0xFFFF;

void test(char *ptr)
{
    if ( (uintptr_t)ptr < foo )
         // do something...
}
```

This is well-defined by the C standard.  The version where you use `void *` instead of `uintptr_t` is undefined behaviour, although it may appear to work if your compiler isn't too aggressive.

Comment: Hmm.  I tried this, and I'm still getting the same warning.

Comment: @Spark check your code carefully, this code would not give a warning. Perhaps the warning comes from another part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably why Linux Kernel uses `unsigned long` for addresses (note the difference -- pointer points to an object, while address is an abstract code representing location in memory).

That's how it seem from compiler perspective:

1. C standard doesn't define how to compare `int` (arithmetic type) literal `0xFFFF` and pointer `address` -- see paragraph *6.5.8*
2. So, it has to convert operands somehow. Both conversions are implementation defined as paragraph *6.3.2.3* states. Here are couple of crazy decisions that compiler eligible to make:

   - Because `0xFFFF` is probably `int` -- see *6.4.4*, it may coerce pointer to `int` and if `sizeof(int) < sizeof(void*)`, you will lose higher bytes.
   - I can imagine more crazier situations when `0xFFFF` is sign extended to `0xFFFFFFFF` (shouldn't be, but why not)

Of course, none of (2) should happen, modern compilers are smart enough. But it can happen (I assume you're writing something embedded, where it is more likely to happen), so that's why compiler raises a warning.

Here is one practical example of "crazy compiler things": in GCC 4.8 optimizer started to treat *integer overflow* as UB (Undefined Behavior) and omit instructions assuming programmer doesn't want *integer overflow*: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61569

I'm referring to *N1570* - C11 standard draft

Comment: Point 2 is wrong; any code that attempts to compare pointer and integer is ill-formed. The programmer must use a cast to select an option.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, but if programmer didn't do that, compiler has to decide how to handle such situation. So point 2 describes potential overcomes to that.

Answer (score -2):

Cast pointer to unsigned int to avoid warnings: `(unsigned)address` - in case of 32 or 16 bit address space.

Comment: The optional type `uintptr_t` exists for this purpose; it's guaranteed to be big enough to hold a pointer.